# VB.NET (If Row(0) es > 10 then Row(1) = "Es mayor a 10" Else if row(0) < 10 then Row(1) = "Es menor a 10" en un datagridview)

Tags: vb.net, .net, datagridview

Hola estoy intentando hacer que la segunda columna me indique si la primera es mayor o menor a 10[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente usando un:

```
 For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

            If row.Cells(0).Value < 10 Then
                row.Cells(1).Value = "El valor es menor a 10"
            Else if row.Cells(0).Value > 10 Then
              row.Cells(1).Value = "El valor es mayor a 10"
            End If
            
        Next
```

Pero la columna resultado me sale en blanco.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda que me puedan dar

Comment: Acabo de probar tu código y funciona. Podía ser alguna configuración del tipo de dato de la columna?

Comment: Ya veo entonce dejame intentarlo pues